# LINQ - How to write a query to set a variable bool True or False

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I use asp.net 4 linq and EF4.

I have this query where CmsSourcesContents is a navigational property.

At he moment when I run the query the result for queryCheck is a type IQuerable.

I need to valuate the condition express in my Linq query but as a result I would like a Type Bool like:

```
bool queryCheck
```

Any idea how to make it? Thanks!

---

```
  var queryCheck = from cnt in context.CmsContents
                   where cnt.ContentId == myContentIdSelected && cnt.CmsSourcesContents.Any()
                   select cnt;
```

---

This query should look for a specific cnt and check if it has any association.. and give me the result as bool.

Comment: You mean, it should be set to true if there are any rows, and false if not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bool queryCheck = (from cnt in context.CmsContents
                  where cnt.ContentId == myContentIdSelected && cnt.CmsSourcesContents.Any()
                  select cnt).Any();
```

Comment: @GibboK standard procedure is to accept this as the answer then :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Any()` again on the total query to see if there are any matches:

```
var queryCheck = (from cnt in context.CmsContents
               where cnt.ContentId == myContentIdSelected && cnt.CmsSourcesContents.Any()
               select cnt).Any();
```